# Can I use MySQL on Django(dev 1.6.x) with Python3.x?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I use Django dev(1.6.x) from git repo and I want to use MySQL , But on the `settings.py` file can not setup MySQL because MySQL is not supported in python3 and Django, So I used pymysql package on python3.x without any problem but in Django can not setup that on `settings.py` too.

Can I use mysql(or pymysql or ?) on django with python3 ?

Comment: You might wish to follow this ticket regarding the support of MySQL on Django with Python 3:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20025 As of today, this feature has to be considered still experimental and requires further testing before being used in production. Please, consider reporting you good or bad experiences!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pymysql for python 3 is not a Django DB backend, however there is evidence that some work has been made porting the MySQL Backend to be Python 3 compatible at [Django Python 3 MySQL backend changes](https://github.com/django/django/commit/bfc380baeaca359ac7b36eb35a2415e6a37e836c).

Other pages show that the MySQL backend given with Django 1.5 works with Python 3 :
[Django MySQL Works on Python 3.2.2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-developers/CtTpgMjN5J8)

The default MySQL wrapper available on Python 2.x (mysql-python) does however not support Python 3.
I suspect the package at [MySQL Python 3](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3) to be compatible, you might give it a try.

Also make sure you're running Django with Python 3.2 or 3.3 or above. Python 3.0 is not supported.

If it still does not work after these checks, please post your DATABASES settings in case something was wrong in it.

Also, I don't find anything above Django 1.5 in the Django repos, are you sure it's 1.6.x ?

Comment: I use python 3.2 and django ('1.6.dev20121106091914') ,I tested [Mysql python3](https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3) and not work after making process,So according to your words, best way is waiting for django support of mysql ?

Comment: This error happend when i use your link (Mysql Py3) : **TypeError: 'use_unicode' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

Comment: @alireza.m you might find this helpful: http://nbensa.blogspot.com.ar/2013/03/python-3-django-and-mysql.html, check out the section "We're almost there. Let's patch Django."

Answer (score 75):

I also struggled with making MySQL work with Django 1.6 and Python 3.3; the only thing that worked was to switch to PyMySQL. See my post on that [**here**](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/)

**Adding the answer below**

My environment: OSX 10.9, Python 3.3.3, Django 1.6.1, PyMySQL 0.6.1, MySQL Server 5.5 on Windows

How to make it work:

1. Install PyMySQL version 0.6.1 (https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/): you can install it either by using pip, i.e. : `pip install PyMySQL` or by manually downloading the package; there is a good documentation on their website on how to do that.
2. Open your Django App **__init__.py** and paste the following lines:

   ```
   import pymysql
   pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
   ```
3. Now, open **settings.py** and make sure your DATABASE property looks like this:

   ```
   DATABASES = {
      'default': {
          'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
          'NAME': 'mydb',
          'USER': 'dbuser',
          'PASSWORD': 'dbpassword',
          'HOST': 'dbhost',
          'PORT': '3306'
       }
   }
   ```
4. That's it, you should be able to execute `python manage.py syncdb` to init your MySQL DB; see the sample output below:

   ```
   Creating tables ...
   Creating table django_admin_log
   Creating table auth_permission
   Creating table auth_group_permissions
   ...
   ...
   Creating table socialaccount_socialtoken

   You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
   ...
   ```

Comment: Why the post was -1'ed ? The link to my post explains exactly how to configure settings.py and make it work.

Comment: I am not the one who downvoted, but I assume that is was because your answer was basically a link-only answer (if the link were removed, there would be little useful left in the answer). See the "Provide context for links" section in [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: Ok, I will just repost it in here. The link is to another place in stackoverflow - I just didn't want to double the post in here as well. Thanks, anyway

Comment: @morgan_il Did you try the Oracle MySQL connector?

Comment: @mattblang Yes, I did - and didn't work. There were some suggestions on how to fix the errors I encountered during that, but all of them required modification in the connectors code which is not the best approach and eventually neither of them worked.

Comment: @morgan_il How is the `PyMySQL` working out for you?  I actually switched back to 2.7 to use `MySql-python`, but would rather be on `3.3`.

Comment: @mattblang So far so good - haven't encountered any errors. DB seems to be aligned with the model. I currently not continuing with the project, but I will definitely go back to it as soon as I have some free time. I also thought about moving back to Python 2.7 because of that issue.

Comment: +1, this is the only solution that works when developing in PTVS. I do get an error "ImportError: cannot import name zip_longest" but that doesn't seem to influence the process.

Answer (score 7):

I've been waiting for mysql support with django and python 3.x for ages and finally there is a somewhat official compatible engine that let's you do this.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-django-backend.html

I created a virtualenv using python 3 and was able to use the database specific settings in the above link.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mydbuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mydbpassword',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Cut and pasted the models from the Django Poll Tutorial and 'python manage syncdb' worked.

More testing to see if the entire ORM supports this connector.

My full write up here:
http://bunwich.blogspot.ca/2014/02/finally-mysql-connector-that-works-with.html

Comment: This looks good and more supported than PyMySQL. Found any differences/pros/cons between them?

Answer (score 6):

I fixed this problem by this:

According to the documentation of Django 1.8 and 1.9, [**mysqlclient** is the recommended driver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers):

> **MySQLdb** is a native driver that has been developed and supported for over a decade by Andy Dustman.
>
> **mysqlclient** is a fork of MySQLdb which notably supports Python 3 and can be used as a drop-in replacement for MySQLdb. At the time of this writing, this is the recommended choice for using MySQL with Django.
>
> **MySQL Connector/Python** is a pure Python driver from Oracle that does not require the MySQL client library or any Python modules outside the standard library.

So, I installed mysqlclient by

```
sudo pip install mysqlclient
```

Config the database in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'mydjango',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306'
    }
}
```

But when I use `./manage.py syncdb` for testing, I received an error saying:

```
_mysql.so not found
```

To fix this, add

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
```

to `~/.bashrc`

Then run:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

It should be fixed now.