# connecting mysql and python3.3

Tags: django, python-3.x, mysql-python

i'm new to django an usind django 1.5 and python 3.3.
Is there any way to install mysqlDB on python 3.3
(or)Is there any other method to connect them ?

Comment: See [Can i use mysql on django(dev 1.6.x) with python3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13320343)

Comment: yes you can with https://github.com/davispuh/MySQL-for-Python-3
@MartijnPieters

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL or 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-versions.html

the second Connector does not support the old MySQL Server authentication methods, which means that MySQL versions prior to 4.1 will not work.

Comment: that works with python 2.7 but not on python 3 .For some reason the team hasn't written the mysql-python installation for python 3

Answer (score 2):

[PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL), a pure python client library without a dependency on the standard mysql client library, has Python 3 support via a build script.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
The windows msi package for the mysql connector installed without any problem and seems to work nicely for a 1.0.10 (on windows 2008 R2 with python 3.3)