# Django and Connector/Python Integration

Tags: django, mysql-python, mysql-connector, python-3.3

How can I setup a Django 1.5.1 app running with Python 3.3 to access a MySQL database? I tried using MySQLdb but apparently it doesn't support Python 3.3.

My next intention was to use Connector/Python, but what am I supposed to put for the "Engine" key of the Databases dictionary of the settings.py file?

If someone could provide detailed steps of how to get Django to work with Connector/Python, that would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15230835/connecting-mysql-and-python3-3

Comment: I'm looking more for step-by-step instructions on how to integrate Connector/Python with Django. I've tried googling this but I can't seem to find a concrete example online. The Django documentation says it can support different MySQL connectors, but doesn't really show you how to use something other than the "default" MySQLdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> MySQLdb is the Python interface to MySQL [supported by django]. Version 1.2.1p2 or later is required for full MySQL support in Django.
>
> At the time of writing, the latest release of MySQLdb (1.2.4) doesn’t support Python 3. In order to use MySQL under Python 3, you’ll have to install an unofficial fork, such as MySQL-for-Python-3.
>
> This port is still in alpha. In particular, it doesn’t support binary data, making it impossible to use django.db.models.BinaryField.

Basically your only options to avoid Alpha quality drivers are:

1. Don't use python 3.
2. Don't use MySQL.

Hopefully this makes the choice easier: http://grimoire.ca/mysql/choose-something-else

REF: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#python-3

Comment: Clear, concise and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!