# Error while using MySql with Python 3.4.3 and Django 1.9.6

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, mysql-python

I have tried using

1. pymysql
2. mysql-client
3. mysql-connector-pyhton

and various other ways stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960048/python-3-and-mysql) but still I am not able to use MySql as my database.

Whenever I try to do run it shows below error message.

`raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`

I have tried these two Database configuration in my setting.py file

Setting 1: This works with python 2.7

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'user_db',
        'USER': 'ecom',
        'PASSWORD': 'ecom@123',
        'HOST': 'localhost',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

error message :

```
`raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'`
```

Setting 2: as suggested in this [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560973/python3-mysql-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'secretpassword',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

error message :

```
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named 'mysql'
```

Still I am not able to use mysql as backend can anyone please let me know what I am doing wrong or is it even possible with python 3.4.3?

I would be really thankful for your help and guidance.

Comment: Try running : pip install mysqlclient ?

Comment: yes, I successfully installed mysqlclient and still facing this issue. @soupboy

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 @soupboy

Comment: try : sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Comment: It's already installed @soupboy