# trouble installing mysql python, mysqldb module not found in django

Tags: mysql, django, windows, python-2.7, pip

I'm using `mysql` with `django` for the first time. Both are installed, I can use `mysql` in the workbench or command prompt, however when I tried migrations in `django`, it can't find the `mysqldb` module, cut most of it out, see below:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "C:\Users\jerro\Desktop\djangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb
```

So i've been trying to use `pip install mysql-python` and can't do it. I've installed `mysql-connector`, `annaconda`, and tried many other suggestions on this and google, no luck. It gives me the error below:

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7
creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release
C:\Users\jerro\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -IC:\Python27\include -Ic:\users\jerro\desktop\djangoenv\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\_mysql.obj /Zl
_mysql.c
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Users\\jerro\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microsoft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
```

```
Command "c:\users\jerro\desktop\djangoenv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\jerro\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-_da1js\\MySQL-python\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\jerro\appdata\local\temp\pip-kqvwr3-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\jerro\desktop\djangoenv\include\site\python2.7\MySQL-python" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\jerro\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-_da1js\MySQL-python\
```

Nothing i've done or tried has worked, any suggestions? i'm using windows10

---

Update, I finally was able to get pip mysql-python installed, now the only error I get is the no module named mysqldb when I try to makemigrations. mysql-connector, mysqlclient is installed, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes **pip install mysqlclient** command doesn't work 
so follow these steps:

1)  search unofficial python binaries or
    go to **https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/**
    and search(ctrl+f)on that page for mysqlclient

2)  check your python version on machine
    and download the **whl** file appropriate for your downloaded python version
    like
    type python in command prompt
    and you will get your python version

```
>python
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 21:26:53) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

this is python 3.7.3 version and works on 32 bit    

so the whl file will be mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl
python 3.7.3 = cp37 and 32 bit is win32
```

3)  download that file and type following code in your environment or where you downloaded the whl file
    **>pip install mysqlclient-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl**

hope this will work

Comment: Works for me, instead having to install VS buildtools.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to [Mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) and install Connector. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Still nothing, I've pip install mysql-connector before but neither that nor this has done any good.