# Unable to install a Library using PIP

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

So I'm trying to follow a tutorial to connect to an SQL database, using Connector/Python.

I have to import it, obviously:

> import mysql.connector

So I tried `pip install mysql` in the terminal.

This is what I got:

**Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g6/yrxcmygn3ls375rm9rh3p86r0000gn/T/pip-build-a0d0rzdl/MySQL-python/**

What I've tried from looking up on Google:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools

pip install ez_setup

pip install unroll

easy_install -U setuptools
```

Nothing worked

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512331/how-to-install-mysql-python-by-pip then maybe see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560973/python3-mysql-error-loading-mysqldb-module-no-module-named-mysqldb/40557340#40557340

Comment: Which OS do you use? Linux, Windows, ...? Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL-Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5) is not available for Python 3, you may consider using [MySqlClient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) which is a fork of the MySQL-python interface for the MySQL database.

Before installing this connector, make sure MySQL (or MariaDB) is installed.

- On Linux, you also need the "devel" packages. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7461662/1513933
- On Windows, you may be interested in the [unofficial Windows binaries](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient).

To install, an application, the best practices is to use a virtualenv.