# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 while starting Django in MySQL DB

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

When I start my server in Django and try to connect the MySql with it. This error appears :/ how to resolve it

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

My python version is 3.7.3 and Django version is 2.2.1. Please guide me. I have seen videos on YouTube but still no help.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Refer to this answer please: [Django - installing mysqlclient error: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required)

Answer (score 0):

Try this via terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade mysqlclient
```

Seems you need upgrade mysqlclient lib that used with Django in this case.

You can check lib versions using pip too.

```
pip freeze | grep mysqlclient
```