# How to fix "mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required you have 0.9.3"?

Tags: python, django

I want to connect my database with Django when I write a command:

python managa.py migrate I get this error,
How do I fix it?

> [...]
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is requ
>   ired; you have 0.9.3.

Comment: Doesn't the error tell you exactly what you need to do? Upgrade mysqlclient.

Comment: I know it but how to do it

Comment: I don't use django but does it have a requirements.txt with package versions listed?

Comment: I think no but maybe i cant find it

Comment: How did you install mysqlclient in the first place?  Just do that, with the newer version.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade mysqlclient` in your virtual environment (but then you should have a *requirements.txt* file somewhere the repository and update the version there) or if you're using pipenv: `pipenv update mysqlclient`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django - installing mysqlclient error: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required)