# Django project doesn't work with MySql database

Tags: mysql, django

I have settings like this

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': os.environ.get('DB_NAME'),
            'USER': os.environ.get('DB_USER'),
            'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DB_PASS'),
            'HOST': os.environ.get('DB_HOST'),
            'PORT': os.environ.get('DB_PORT')
        }
```

in my main **init** file I added these lines:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

I have error like this now:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

I found [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954355/3316855) in stackoverflow, but it is bad solution. Because when i to try start my django project in the server, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you upgrade `MySQL`? Error message clearly says: `mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3`

Comment: You need to install MySQL Connector.

Comment: @caot yes! Thanks. This is correct answer!!!

Comment: @KamalNayan if it was used like you said, I would not create a question