# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX' when connecting google cloud store with django

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, gcloud

I am connecting google cloudstore mysql with django using official documentation on app engine environment, given as: https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine
Firstly, I got the error that mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required. To resolve this issue, I used the solution given on [Django - installing mysqlclient error: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required), but when I do this it gives me the error "AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute 'AFX_UNIT'".

Comment: What solution have you picked? And what version of Django do you have?