# why i cannot able to connect to mysql with python?

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

> C:\Users\alurilalith.sag\Desktop\website>python manage.py runserver
>   Watching for file changes with StatReloader Exception in thread
>   django-main-thread: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or
>   newer is required; you have 0.9.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - installing mysqlclient error: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required)

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but what is it that you don't understand in the error message ? It clearly states, in all letters, that your currently installed version (0.9.3) of the `mysqlclient` package is not compatible with your version of django and must be upgraded to 1.3.13 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you either hav pinned the package version of `mysqlclient` to version `0.9.3` or one of your other dependencies requires the package in this version.

Have you tried updating `mysqlclient`? The [current release on pypi is 1.4.6](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/1.4.6/)

If you are using a `requirements.txt` try changing

`mysqlclient==0.9.3` or just `mysqlclient`

to

`mysqlclient==1.3.13`