# unable to proceed further due to the error of 'update mysql client'

Tags: mysql, django, backend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfJDh.png)

Can someone please explain what exactly is this error and what should i do? Because i have tried updating mysql on my laptop to get rid of the error but it still says the same

updated mysql, still no change

Comment: Updated what? How?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the minimum required version of mysqlclient or newer

```
pip install mysqlclient==1.4.3
```

OR

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

MySQL and mysqlclient are different MySql is the database itself and [mysqlclient](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/) is the client used to access the database

---

EDIT: Create a Virtual Environment to isolate your project required  dependencies

**1 Install [virtual Environment](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/venv.html) to isolate your project**
To create a virtual env:

1. Create a new directory to stock your virtual environment :

> c:\my_virtual_env

2. create the virtual env:

> cd C:\my_virtual_env
> "C:\my_virtual_env"  py -m venv database_project_venv"

**2 Activate the virtual environment**

```
C:\my_virtual_env\database_project_venv\Scripts\activate
```

You should have something like that displayed in your terminal :

```
(database_project_venv) c:\my_virtual_env
```

To deactivate the virtual environment use the command deactivate. For example: `(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_11>> deactivate`

**3 Install Django**

Still in your virtual environment, install Django:

```
1. Upgrade pip : `(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1> python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

2. Install Django: `(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1> pip install django`

3. Check django Version : `(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1> django-admin --version`
```

**4 Create your Django project**

```
(database_project_venv) c:\> cd C:\database_project_1 
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1> django-admin startproject database_project
```

You should have something like this

> c:\database_project_1\database_project\

**5 Create you app**

```
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1> cd database_project
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> python manage.py startapp my_app
```

Configure your *settings.py* by adding your app to the in *INSTALLED_APPS*

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
…
    'my_app.apps.MyAppConfig',
…
]
```

**6 Configure your MySql**

In settings.py, configure your database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost', # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

**7 Database initialization**

```
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> python manage.py makemigrations
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> python manage.py migrate
```

**8 Create SuperUser**
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> python manage.py createsuperuser

Update your project as needed

Now install your mysqlclient

```
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> pip install mysqlclient
```

Try to run your project

```
(database_project_venv) c:\database_project_1\database_project> python manage.py runserver
```

Tell if everything works correctly now

Comment: i did what you asked me to and it gave this message : https://imgur.com/lGPmWOi                                                                                                        however when i tried to run the file, it gave me this error : https://imgur.com/ANOp1Mm                                                                                               so i tried the first code you asked me to run but it gave some other error :          https://imgur.com/twKUkg4               I'm sorry if this is a lot but i really need to rectify this for a project i have to submit in 4 days

Comment: From your screenshot, it seems that you have environment configuration conflicts and  the installed application are not correctly detected. Furthermore you're not using virtual environment.
I'll edit my answer to help you install a Django project with Virtualenv. 
Please tell me if it solves the problem.

Comment: i followed the steps in your comment and in the database initialization part when i run the first command : "python manage.py makemigrations"  it gives me the following error: https://imgur.com/EtPYTzg    (this is the error i got the second time i tried to do everything from the beginning, following your steps. the first time when i tried this and i got the error, instead of doing the database initialization, i first did pip install mysqlclient and then did the database initialization, however that time, it gave the same error saying i have the old version of mysqlclient and needed to update)

Comment: okay so i think its fine, cuz its up and running now. i searched up for why i was getting the same error always and finally found a stack overflow post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required/59591269#59591269                                          This comment cleared it out. Nevertheless, thank you so much for taking your time and helping me out !!

Comment: Really glad I was able to help you. Good luck for you project.