# Access Denied when connection to mysql in Django

Tags: mysql, django, pymysql

In my newly created django project, I configured MySQL connection instead of default sqlite3. When I ran `python manage.py runserver`, I receive access denied error:
[image: Access denied]

The Django complains wrong user&password, but I think both are correct as I repeatedly login mysql cli console with both. Any tips and suggestion for these `access denied` appreciated.

Following are some backgrounds.

The python is 3.9 in ubuntu22.04. The django project is newly created, and I use `pymysql` instead of mysqlclient for mysql operation. Therefore, I only made two changes:

1. init pymysql

[Code sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657752/django-installing-mysqlclient-error-mysqlclient-1-3-13-or-newer-is-required)

```
import pymysql                                                                                                 
pymysql.version_info=(1,4,3,"final",0)
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

2. Configure the MySQL connection info

[image: MySql cli sample and Database config in setting.py]

3. I also tried the same in the python console, and shows the user&password should be ok.

```
    >>> import pymysql
    >>> conn = pymysql.connect(
    ...         host='localhost',
    ...         user='test', 
    ...         password = "test",
    ...         db='xxx',
    ...         )
    >>> conn
    <pymysql.connections.Connection object at 0x7f065c51ebe0>
    >>> cur = conn.cursor()
    >>> cur
    <pymysql.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7f065ccd0ee0>
    >>> cur.execute("select @@version")
    1
    >>> output = cur.fetchall()
    >>> print(output)
    (('8.0.32-0ubuntu0.22.04.2',),)
    >>> conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have typo in USER in django settings.

```
test`
```