# Celery, Django and PyMySQL

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python, pymysql, celerybeat

I have a django application hooked to a MySQL database, which uses **PyMySQL** rather than MySQLdb. See the popular answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13320343/can-i-use-mysql-on-djangodev-1-6-x-with-python3-x) for more details on that.

Now, it is necessary for me to create a **periodic task** using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/). I have followed  the documentation for periodic tasks [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html).

When I run the command `celery -A proj beat` I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 96, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 264, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 124, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 198, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 113, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 17, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

It compains about a MySQLdb module, but I don't think I am using MySQLdb. Could anybody offer any advice on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and was able to fix it by adding the following to the celery app:

```
import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()
```

Answer (score 0):

Install suitable mysql client for you computer operate system will fix this problem.:)
in python 2.x you should: `sudo pip install MySQL-python`
in python 3.x you should: `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Comment: I guess the OP has to either switch to MySQLdb from PyMySQL or tell Django/Celery to use PyMySQL. Just installing MySQLdb won't solve the problem.

Comment: And now i use PyMySQL in python3-sqlalchemy and use mysql+pymysql driver : `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = ('mysql+pymysql://username:password@my-ip:mysql-port/db-name?charset=utf8')`